# Removing shadow from card layout

Tags: android, shadow, cardlayout

I want to remove shadow from the default card layout that i am using by setting `android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"`.How can i do it?

```
<com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
        android:numColumns="3"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchtext"
        app:item_margin="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridgip"

        />
```

Comment: Where is your card layout?

Comment: @Harry      android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" creates default card background..i want to remove shadow from it

Comment: Are u assigning background to whole grid view or its itmes? and you can't modify default drawables of android! Create your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use that background use your own background with color. Just remove the code and give some color code like this:

```
android:background = "FF0000" //this is for RED color
```

Use your custom color by putting hex color code.
Follow this link: http://html-color-codes.info/